# Adding class to input in Play 2 custom FieldConstructor

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am making a custom field constructor in Play 2:

```
@(elements : helper.FieldElements)

<div class="@if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">
    <label for="@elements.id">@elements.label</label>
    <div class="input">
        @elements.input
        <span class="errors">@elements.errors.mkString(", ")</span>
        <span class="help">@elements.infos.mkString(", ")</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need the input element to always have a particular class "my-class". How can I do this? The FieldElements class has an args member.  I tried making a copy of the elements with " my-class" appended to the value associated with '_class in args, but this did not seem to affect the input element.

Answer (score 3):

One way for custom input in Play Framework is

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)
<div class="form-group @elements.args.get('_class) @if(elements.hasErrors) {has-error}" id="@elements.args.get('_id).getOrElse(elements.id + "_field")">

    @if(elements.hasName) {
        <label class="control-label" for="@elements.id">@elements.name</label>
    } else {
        <label class="control-label" for="@elements.id">@elements.label(elements.lang)</label>
    }

    @if(elements.input.toString().contains("class=")) {

        @Html(elements.input.toString().replaceFirst("(class=[\"'])", "$1form-control "))

    } else {

        @Html(elements.input.toString().replaceFirst("(<\\w+ )", "$1class=\"form-control\" "))

    }


    @elements.errors.map { error =>
        <p class="help-block">@error</p>
    }

    @elements.infos.map { info =>
        <span class="help-block">@info</span>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
@inputText(myForm("fieldName"), 'class -> "my-class")
```

UPDATE:

Ok, you want to override the `@element.input` right? You can have a look at the source code and create your own tag (helper): https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/inputText.scala.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. What you've done is actually what I want to avoid. I want all inputs to have the "my-class" class, so I am trying to create a custom FieldConstructor in order to avoid always manually adding my-class to every form element.

Answer (score 1):

In your Field constructor replace

```
@elements.input
```

with:

```
@Html(elements.input.body.dropRight(2)+"class='form-control'>")
```

this might not be the most correct One but It would do the job
but watch for the text area this would need extra efforts.

Comment: This is a bad approach because it stops you from adding classes normally (ie, with `'class -> "class1 class2"` in the input helper).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Nguyen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29275792/469218) I created a more robust method that will only modify desired elements and will also reuse the regular expressions.

```
object Helper {
  import views.html.helper.FieldConstructor
  implicit val inlineBootstrapConstructor = FieldConstructor(fieldConstructorTemplate.f)

  val classRegex = "(?s)(<(?:input|textarea|select)[^>]*\\sclass=[\"'])".r
  val noClassRegex = "(?s)(<(?:input|textarea|select))((?:(?!\\sclass=\").+)>)".r

  def addClassValue(text: String, classValue: String) = {
    val str = classRegex.replaceFirstIn(text, s"$$1$classValue ")
    noClassRegex.replaceFirstIn(str, s"""$$1 class="$classValue"$$2""")
  }
}
```

The method is pretty straight forward, it tries to modify the `class` element of the first `input`, `textarea` or `select` HTML element and then it creates the `class` element if it doesn't already exist. You can add more elements to the `input|textarea|select` list if necessary. This works perfect for some bootstrap templates where you have to embed some elements in another `div`.

Then, in your template, simply import this method and call it with your class value:

```
@(elements : helper.FieldElements)

@import Helper.addClassValue

@input = @{ addClassValue(elements.input.toString(), "form-control") }

<div class="@if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">
    <label for="@elements.id">@elements.label</label>
    <div class="input">
        @Html(input)
        <span class="errors">@elements.errors.mkString(", ")</span>
        <span class="help">@elements.infos.mkString(", ")</span>
    </div>
</div>
```